Show that the constant term of a generating function is not null
Given a positive integer $n$, is there a standard/simple argument to show that the constant term of the following generating function:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1}\right)^{2n}}{x^{n(2n-1)}}$$
is not null?

I suppose the expression is interpreted as designating a Laurent series, in $\Bbb Z((x))$ for instance. The question is then equivalent to showing that the numerator has a nonzero term in degree $n(2n-1)=2n^2-n$.

This is quite easy. The factor $\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1}=\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}$ in the numerator is in fact a polynomial $1+x+\cdots+x^{2n-1}$ (by the formula for finite geometric sums), which has non-negative coefficients, and positive coefficients in the range $0\leq{d}\leq{2n-1}$ of degrees$~d$. Taking it to the power $2n$ we get a polynomial with positive coefficients in the range $0\leq{d}\leq{2n(2n-1)}$. This range contains (precisely half-way) the power $n(2n-1)$ of $x$ by which one is dividing, so the quotient has a non-zero term in degree$~0$.

Define the support of a Laurent series $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}a_nx^n$ to be $\{n\in \mathbb Z\mid a_n\neq 0\}$. Also, if $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $\mathbb Z$, define $S+T=\{s+t\mid s\in S,t\in T\}$. This lemma is easy to prove.

Lemma: If $f$ and $g$ are power series with nonnegative coefficients, then $$\text{support}(f\cdot g)=\text{support}(f)+\text{support}(g).$$

Now, consider $f(x)=\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1}=1+x+\dots+x^{2n-1}$. Clearly, $\text{support}(f)=\{0,1,\dots,2n-1\}$. If we let $S=\{0,1,\dots,2n-1\}$, then repeatedly applying the lemma, we get
$$
\text{support}\left(f(x)^{2n}\right)=\underbrace{S+\dots+S}_{2n\text{ times}}=\{0,1,\dots,(2n-1)\cdot 2n\}
$$
This further implies
$$
\text{support}\left(\frac{f(x)^{2n}}{x^{n(2n-1)}}\right)=\{-n(2n-1),-n(2n-1)+1,\dots,(2n-1)\cdot 2n-n(2n-1)\}
$$
Since $0$ is in the interval $\{-n(2n-1),\dots,(2n-1)\cdot 2n-n(2n-1)\}$, we conclude that $\frac{f(x)^{2n}}{x^{n(2n-1)}}$  has a nonzero constant term.

First, note that the function can be written as
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1}\right)^{2n} x^{-n(2n-1)}=\left(\frac{x^{n}-x^{-n}}{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}\right)^{2n}$$
If we substitute $x=e^{i\theta}$, the question translates into finding the zeroth Fourier coefficient in the Fourier expansion of $g(\theta)=f(e^{i\theta})$:
$$g(\theta)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n\theta}=\left(\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\right)^{2n}$$
(Note that $g(\theta+2\pi)=\left(-\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\right)^{2n}=g(\theta)$, so $g(\theta)$ is indeed $2\pi$-periodic. Also, $g(\theta)\to (2n)^{2n}$ as $n\to 0$ and thus $g(\theta)$ is well-defined for all $\theta$.) The constant term can then be extracted by Fourier's trick:
$$c_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)^{2n}d\theta$$
Note that the integrand is nonnegative and is zero only if $n\theta$ is a nonzero multiple of $\pi$. Hence the integrand is positive almost everywhere and thus $c_0>0$.


$g$ is in fact an even function of $\theta$, so we could instead instead as a Fourier cosine series. But that seems unnecessary here. 2) For increasing $n$, $g$ is well-approximated as a Gaussian and thus can be approximated by Laplace's method. This yields $c_0\sim \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}2^{2n-1}n^{2n-3/2}$.

